# Have I understood sessions/multi-dimensional arrays properly?

Tags: php

Am I doing the following correctly?

I have an array, which I want to save to a session, so I can use it later in my web application:

```
$data = array(
        "id" => $_POST["id"],
        "r1" => $_POST["r1"],
        "r2" => $_POST["r2"],
        "r3" => $_POST["r3"]);
```

I save it to a session like this:

```
$_SESSION['settings'] = $data;
```

Now, I am not sure how to make use of this later in my application.

Do I do the following

```
$id = $_SESSION['settings']['id'];
$r1 = $_SESSION['settings']['r1'];
```

or do I do the following

```
$data = $_SESSION['settings'];

$id = $data['id'];
$r1 = $data['r1'];
```

or do I do something else?

Comment: Have you tried any of these two options? Did it work or which problems did you get?

Comment: Your question is not actually about sessions but about multi-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do both as `$_SESSION['settings']` points to an array, the two expressions will be identical:

```
// The expression...
$val = $_SESSION['settings']['id'];
// ... is an internal shorthand for ...
$tmp = $_SESSION['settings']; // $tmp never exist - just to aid explanation.
$val = $tmp['id'];
```

Answer (score 4):

Both those methods are perfectly valid ways of doing it. It's probably worth putting some defensive coding in there however.
eg.

```
$id = "";
if (ISSET($SESSION["settings"]) && ISSET($SESSION["settings"]["id"])
{
    $id = $SESSION["settings"]["id"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to use `session_start();` before setting/using variables.
Then set the variables as you did. Not 100% sure, but both ways should work.
When you finish working with session, dont forget to destroy it `session_destroy();`.

Answer (score 0):

Do whatever you need to solve your problem. In your case, both ways are acceptable of working with sessions. If I were you, I would choose the first example when only need to acces 1 or 2 elements from the session and the secon example to access more than 2 (in order to type less ).